# PHP + Ajax Login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Just having a few issues submitting a login form via ajax, I am primarily a PHP developer, I don't use Jquery + Ajax all that often with PHP.

At the moment If i check the firebug POST data after the form has been submit it does appear to get the username and password that have been added to the form, however the page just reloads regardless of whether an incorrect username and password are added or if they are correct and no session is created.

This is the form:

```
    <form id="loginform" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="">

    Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="">

    <input type="submit" name="loginsub" id="loginsub" value="Login">
    </form>
```

This is the Ajax/Jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#loginform').submit(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/class/login.php',
        data: {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val()
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            if (data === 'Login') {
                window.location.replace('/user-page.php');
            }
            else {
                alert('Invalid Credentials');
            }
        }
    });

});

});
</script>
```

And this is the PHP:

```
    class Users {
 public $username = null;
 public $password = null;

 public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
     if( isset( $data['username'] ) ) $this->username = stripslashes(        strip_tags( $data['username'] ) );
     if( isset( $data['password'] ) ) $this->password = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['password'] ) );
 }

 public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
    $this->__construct( $params ); 
 }

 public function Login() {
     $success = false;
     try{
        $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ); 
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";
                    $user = username;

        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "password", md5($this->password), PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();

        $valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        if( $valid ) {
        $success = true;
                    session_start();


        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user['user'];
        session_write_close();
        echo ('Login');
        exit();

        }

        $con = null;
        return $success;
        }catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return $success;
     }

 }
```

I guess it is not working because I am not calling the class and function, but I am not sure how to succesfully do so. I tried creating a controller page in between the 2 that would initiate the php class and function but to no avail.

Just to edit, the login does work correctly if I remove the ajax and just call the php page via the login form action.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use md5 to hash passwords, use bcrypt.

Comment: @WaleedKhan What's wrong with md5?

Comment: Should have explained, I use crypt in live versions, MD5 is only there while I am testing.

Comment: So if you use `/class/login.php` as the form action(without ajax) it works? even without instantiating the user class?

Comment: [This](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode) is the best encryption -- hashing and salting  functions that i have found. they are well tested and very easy to use.  **PHP PBKDF2**

Comment: @Mooseman [md5 generates hashes too fast](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12806381/344643).

Comment: Please don't delete your question after getting an acceptable answer.  Leave it so that others can see your problem/solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

whole issue is in jquery use this instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loginform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '/class/login.php',
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(data)
       {
          if (data === 'Login') {
            window.location = '/user-page.php';
          }
          else {
            alert('Invalid Credentials');
          }
       }
   });
 });
});
```

Comment: That has solved the Ajax issue, it is correctly posting to the PHP now. I knew there was something wrong with that piece of code. 
I still have an error, but it is just regarding the way PHP handles the errors.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
 $user = new User(array("username" => $_POST['username'], "password" => $_POST['password']));
 $user->Login();
```

Put the code above into an login.php controller file (including your users class). Or write a general controller that handles the requests.

Comment: That is close to the controller I tried before. Just gave yours a go but It does the same thing, just reloads the page without creating a session etc.
Seems to me like the Ajax isn't working as if I enter the wrong details it doesn't output the alert either.