# PHP Securitywise why md5 is not considered safe anymore?

Tags: php, security

For a long time as a php developer, i have been using md5 hashing algorithm to secure the password data and to generate unique hashing algorithms.

However from last few months i hear rumors that md5 is not considered secure anymore, i like to know why ?

what are the password authentication alternatives i.e SHA1, password_hash() in PHP 5.5 ?  And i like to know why these alternatives are considered better choice now a days, because to me most of these are again just another hashing algorithms ...

Comment: [`Read its history on Wikipedia`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)

Comment: @Fred-ii- In where does the history says why its insecure anymore ?

Comment: Have you not read any of it, from the link I provided above?

Comment: [`Read this answer then on SO`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12806381/) given by a **255k** member.

Comment: Or, you can continue using it, and find out for yourself, *eventually*. Learning the hard way is *one way* to learn. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Because many websites and [`research studies`](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11426639_2) have proved that `md5()` can be reversed and you should stop using that !

In simple words....

[image]

You could very well make use of [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) in PHP **5.5** and also the [`crypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) those are the better ones considered so far.

A simple illustration of `password_hash()` taken from PHP Manual

```
<?php
$options = [
    'cost' => 12,
];
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
?>
```

A simple illustration of `crypt` making using of the `BLOWFISH` algorithm

```
if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1) {
    echo 'Blowfish:     ' . crypt('rasmuslerdorf', '$2a$07$usesomesillystringforsalt$') . "\n";
}
```

**`EDIT :`**

### Why you should not use `md5()` ?

> Hashing algorithms such as MD5, SHA1 and SHA256 are designed to be
> very fast and efficient. With modern techniques and computer
> equipment, it has become trivial to "brute force" the output of these
> algorithms, in order to determine the original input. Because of how
> quickly a modern computer can "reverse" these hashing algorithms, many
> security professionals strongly suggest against their use for password
> hashing.

### Why go for `password_hash()` on PHP 5.5 ?

> When hashing passwords, the two most important considerations are the
> computational expense, and the salt. The more computationally
> expensive the hashing algorithm, the longer it will take to brute
> force its output. PHP 5.5 provides a native password hashing API which is the **password_hash()** that
> safely handles both hashing and verifying passwords in a secure
> manner.

[`Source`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash)

Comment: You could also consider using `bcrypt` as well. I've found it very secure for my purposes. [link to the github](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, Good you can feel free to edit my answer with that. **+1**

Comment: Nope. your answer is great as it stands, just adding in my2cp :)

Comment: I for one don't know why that when I try to use `password_hash()` on all my servers (PHP 5.3+) that I get this error message `Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash()` @ShankarDamodaran any idea why? The manual says `PHP 5 >= 5.5.0` does that not mean 5.0+ or does it mean that it must be 5.5?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, That is because `password_hash()` is available from PHP 5.5 :P , not on versions prior to that.

Comment: Ok, thanks Shankar. I don't know why PHP.net shows `PHP 5 >= 5.5.0` I guess I misunderstood what they meant by that, and thought it was PHP 5+ @ShankarDamodaran +1 ;-)

Comment: i guess my question is mainly why md5 is insecure, and if you say password_hash is better how it can be better than md5.. that the more of the question..

Comment: The OP is looking for the actual "machine code" or an "assembler" method of explanation (*if you get my meaning*). Seems like the explanations and reasons given, just have not been satisfying enough; till it's too late ;-) @ShankarDamodaran - I for one never liked going to the "School of hard knocks". It's just too painful ;-) Voted to close as "unclear what is asked".

Comment: Yeah the research studies link I provided earlier (on the top) , exactly explains that :)

Comment: Yes I noticed and even then, you didn't have to go to those lengths, but very very good though! I voted to close as "unclear what is asking". @ShankarDamodaran - Seems there's no pleasing here. Funny graphic by the way! lol

Comment: Please elaborate on "many websites and research studies have proved that `md5()` can be reversed". I won’t accept simple look-up or rainbow tables as answer.

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran: IMHO: No need to duplicate content, also not from the PHP manual (and you miss to give credits even). Also the study you've linked, I wonder how it fits. And the image you've posted, it's pretty low for an answer to my taste. Especially due to the duplicate material.

Comment: @hakre, Added the source. Assumed that this content was available on the earlier linked manual of `password_hash()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's fast. An attacker could break a hashed password in just a few hours (maybe minutes) if they managed to get a copy of your database - the faster an algorithm, the more attempts per second = more insecure.

SHA-256/SHA-512 are better choices as they take longer to process, therefore they could add  years to the time it could take to break a hash. Not sure about the hackers out there, but I don't have the time or patience to try that.