# How to compare hashed password from db and login password entered into GUI login system made with tkinter

Tags: python, password-hash

so I'm new to Python but I had to make a login system using either python or web app. I decided to go with a GUI using tkinter, this was done with a couple of days' worth of research on it so feel free to tell me if there's anything I could have done better with the code I found.

The project was making a register and login system using hash and salt. The hash and salt must be seen in the database when opening the db. So far, I've managed to do that. I can register, and when pressing login it checks if there's a row in the DB with those exact info and returns them in the console, otherwise it returns none.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import sqlite3
import hashlib


# Designing window for registration

def register():
    global register_screen
    register_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    register_screen.title("Register")
    register_screen.geometry("300x250")

    global username
    global password
    global salt
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    global salt_entry
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()
    salt = StringVar()

    Label(register_screen, text="Please enter details below", bg="blue").pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    username_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Username * ")
    username_lable.pack()
    username_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=username)
    username_entry.pack()
    password_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Password * ")
    password_lable.pack()
    password_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=password, show='*')
    password_entry.pack()
    salt_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Salt * ")
    salt_lable.pack()
    salt_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=salt)
    salt_entry.pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    Button(register_screen, text="Register", width=10, height=1, bg="blue", command=register_user).pack()


# Designing window for login

def login():
    global login_screen
    login_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    login_screen.title("Login")
    login_screen.geometry("300x250")
    Label(login_screen, text="Please enter details below to login").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()

    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    global username_login_entry
    global password_login_entry

    Label(login_screen, text="Username * ").pack()
    username_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=username_verify)
    username_login_entry.pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="Password * ").pack()
    password_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=password_verify, show='*')
    password_login_entry.pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Button(login_screen, text="Login", width=10, height=1, command=login_verify).pack()


# Implementing event on register button

def register_user():
    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()
    salt_info = salt.get()
    salted = (password_info+salt_info)
    hashed = hashlib.sha256(salted.encode()).hexdigest()


    conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (Username TEXT, Password TEXT, Salt TEXT)')
    c.execute('INSERT INTO user (Username, Password, salt) VALUES(?,?,?)', (username_info, password_info, salted))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

    Label(register_screen, text="Registration Success", fg="green", font=("Calibri", 11)).pack()


# Implementing event on login button

def login_verify():
    username1 = username_verify.get()
    password1 = password_verify.get()
    username_login_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_login_entry.delete(0, END)


    conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username='%s' AND Password='%s'" % (username1, password1))
    print(c.fetchone())

# Designing popup for login success

def login_sucess():
    global login_success_screen
    login_success_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    login_success_screen.title("Success")
    login_success_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(login_success_screen, text="Login Success").pack()
    Button(login_success_screen, text="OK", command=delete_login_success).pack()


# Designing popup for login invalid password

def password_not_recognised():
    global password_not_recog_screen
    password_not_recog_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    password_not_recog_screen.title("Success")
    password_not_recog_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(password_not_recog_screen, text="Invalid Password ").pack()
    Button(password_not_recog_screen, text="OK", command=delete_password_not_recognised).pack()


# Designing popup for user not found

def user_not_found():
    global user_not_found_screen
    user_not_found_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    user_not_found_screen.title("Success")
    user_not_found_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(user_not_found_screen, text="User Not Found").pack()
    Button(user_not_found_screen, text="OK", command=delete_user_not_found_screen).pack()


# Deleting popups

def delete_login_success():
    login_success_screen.destroy()


def delete_password_not_recognised():
    password_not_recog_screen.destroy()


def delete_user_not_found_screen():
    user_not_found_screen.destroy()


# Designing Main(first) window

def main_account_screen():
    global main_screen
    main_screen = Tk()
    main_screen.geometry("300x250")
    main_screen.title("Account Login")
    Label(text="Select Your Choice", bg="blue", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Login", height="2", width="30", command=login).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Register", height="2", width="30", command=register).pack()

    main_screen.mainloop()


main_account_screen()
```

With this code it works but I want to remove the password from the db as well as the salted password and only keep the hashed password as well as the salt so: username ; salt ; hashed password.
**Now my question is, when I login, how would I have to do it to compare the hashed password and the password entered?** I was thinking, find username in db > retrieve salt from db > add it to password entered > compare it to hashed password. Or should I add an "enter your salt" box in the login window as well?

I changed 2 blocks of code to this:

```
def register_user():
    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()
    salt_info = salt.get()
    salted = (password_info+salt_info)
    hashed = hashlib.sha256(salted.encode()).hexdigest()


    conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (Username TEXT, Salt TEXT, Hashed TEXT)')
    c.execute('INSERT INTO user (Username, Salt, Hashed) VALUES(?,?,?)', (username_info, salt_info, hashed))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def login_verify():
    username1 = username_verify.get()
    password1 = password_verify.get()
    username_login_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_login_entry.delete(0, END)


    conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username='%s' AND Hashed='%s'" % (username1, password1))
    print(c.fetchone())
```

Answer (score 0):

I vote to retrieve the salt from the db :)

Db should have the salt and the hashed password. The best advice I can find about how to do this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188507/how-do-i-implement-salt-into-my-login-for-passwords)

I like this part in particular:

"Use a non-null column of existing valid data to build your salt on (blowfish-encrypted string of username based on a secret encryption key is usually cryptographically secure). Do not use a separate column for the salt. If you cannot use an existing column, incorporate your salt in the same column than your hash. For example, use the first 32 characters for your 128-bits salt and then the last 40 for your 160-bits hash."