# AES encryption in JS equivalent of C#

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I need to encrypt a string using AES encryption. This encryption was happening in C# earlier, but it needs to be converted into JavaScript (will be run on a browser).

The current code in C# for encryption is as following -

```
public static string EncryptString(string plainText, string encryptionKey)
{
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);

    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())

    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))

            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            plainText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return plainText;
}
```

I have tried to use CryptoJS to replicate the same functionality, but it's not giving me the equivalent encrypted base64 string. Here's my CryptoJS code -

```
function encryptString(encryptString, secretKey) {
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('Ivan Medvedev');
    var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(secretKey, iv, { keySize: 256 / 32, iterations: 500 });

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encryptString, key,{iv:iv);
    return encrypted;
}
```

The encrypted string has to be sent to a server which will be able to decrypt it. The server is able to decrypt the encrypted string generated from the C# code, but not the encrypted string generated from JS code. I tried to compare the encrypted strings generated by both the code and found that the C# code is generating longer encrypted strings. For example keeping 'Example String' as plainText and 'Example Key' as the key, I get the following result -

```
C# - eAQO+odxOdGlNRB81SHR2XzJhyWtz6XmQDko9HyDe0w=
JS - 9ex5i2g+8iUCwdwN92SF+A==
```

The length of JS encrypted string is always shorter than the C# one. Is there something I am doing wrong? I just have to replicated the C# code into the JS code.

**Update:**
My current code after [Zergatul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53784853/1079901) is this -

```
function encryptString(encryptString, secretKey) {
    var keyBytes = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(secretKey, 'Ivan Medvedev', { keySize: 48 / 4, iterations: 1000 });
    console.log(keyBytes.toString());

    // take first 32 bytes as key (like in C# code)
    var key = new CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.init(keyBytes.words, 32);
    // skip first 32 bytes and take next 16 bytes as IV
    var iv = new CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.init(keyBytes.words.splice(32 / 4), 16);

    console.log(key.toString());
    console.log(iv.toString());

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encryptString, key, { iv: iv });
    return encrypted;
}
```

As illustrated in his/her answer that if the C# code converts the plainText into bytes using ASCII instead of Unicode, both the C# and JS code will produce exact results. But since I am not able to modify the decryption code, I have to convert the code to be equivalent of the original C# code which was using Unicode.

So, I tried to see, what's the difference between both the bytes array between ASCII and Unicode byte conversion in C#. Here's what I found -

```
ASCII Byte Array: [69,120,97,109,112,108,101,32,83,116, 114, 105, 110, 103]
Unicode Byte Array: [69,0,120,0,97,0,109,0,112,0,108,0,101,0,32,0,83,0,116,0, 114,0, 105,0, 110,0, 103,0]
```

So some extra bytes are available for each character in C# (So Unicode allocates twice as much bytes to each character than ASCII).

Here's the difference between both Unicode and ASCII conversion respectively -

```
ASCII
clearBytes: [69,120,97,109,112,108,101,32,83,116,114,105,110,103,]
encryptor.Key: [123,213,18,82,141,249,182,218,247,31,246,83,80,77,195,134,230,92,0,125,232,210,135,115,145,193,140,239,228,225,183,13,]
encryptor.IV: [101,74,46,177,46,233,68,252,83,169,211,13,249,61,118,167,]
Result: eQus9GLPKULh9vhRWOJjog==

Unicode:
clearBytes: [69,0,120,0,97,0,109,0,112,0,108,0,101,0,32,0,83,0,116,0,114,0,105,0,110,0,103,0,]
encryptor.Key: [123,213,18,82,141,249,182,218,247,31,246,83,80,77,195,134,230,92,0,125,232,210,135,115,145,193,140,239,228,225,183,13,]
encryptor.IV: [101,74,46,177,46,233,68,252,83,169,211,13,249,61,118,167,]
Result: eAQO+odxOdGlNRB81SHR2XzJhyWtz6XmQDko9HyDe0w=
```

So since both the key and iv being generated have exact same byte array in both Unicode and ASCII approach, it should not have generated different output, but somehow it's doing that. I think it's because of clearBytes' length, as it's using its length to write to CryptoStream.

I tried to see what's the output of the generated bytes in the JS code is and found that it uses words which needed to be converted into Strings using `toString()` method.

```
keyBytes: 7bd512528df9b6daf71ff653504dc386e65c007de8d2877391c18cefe4e1b70d654a2eb12ee944fc53a9d30df93d76a7
key: 7bd512528df9b6daf71ff653504dc386e65c007de8d2877391c18cefe4e1b70d
iv: 654a2eb12ee944fc53a9d30df93d76a7
```

Since, I am not able to affect the generated encrypted string's length in the JS code (No access to the write stream directly), thus still stuck here.

Comment: It seems that the key generations are different. At least the number of [iterations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netframework-4.7.2); `//The default iteration count is 1000 so the two methods use the`

Comment: @kelalaka Well Spotted! I have tried with keeping iteration count as 1000 too. Didn't change much.

Comment: If you look at the documentation [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netframework-4.7.2) and the [source code](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/src/pbkdf2.js) of JS, You have to find a way to match the parameter for PBKDF2. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209486/reproducing-js-pbkdf2-hash-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1&lq=1) may help you. This maybe the first bug of your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the example how to reproduce the same ciphertext between `C#` and `CryptoJS`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] plainText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Example String"); // this is UTF-16 LE
    string cipherText;
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        var pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("Example Key", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Ivan Medvedev"));
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(cipherText);
}
```

And JS:

```
var keyBytes = CryptoJS.PBKDF2('Example Key', 'Ivan Medvedev', { keySize: 48 / 4, iterations: 1000 });
// take first 32 bytes as key (like in C# code)
var key = new CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.init(keyBytes.words, 32);
// skip first 32 bytes and take next 16 bytes as IV
var iv = new CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.init(keyBytes.words.splice(32 / 4), 16);
// use the same encoding as in C# code, to convert string into bytes
var data = CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE.parse("Example String");
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, { iv: iv });
console.log(encrypted.toString());
```

Both codes return: `eAQO+odxOdGlNRB81SHR2XzJhyWtz6XmQDko9HyDe0w=`

Comment: Thanks @Zergatul for the answer. This solves one part of the problem (dividing up key and iv's bytes), but my problem is that the C# code is not modifiable. That means the String generated by my C# code is the actual valid encrypted string which the server is able to understand. So I need the exact functionality of the earlier C# code. 
Your code explained to me what's the difference now. The initial bytes generated from the "Example String" is in ASCII in your code instead of Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** the final code looks like this -

```
function encryptString(encryptString, secretKey) {
    encryptString = addExtraByteToChars(encryptString);
    var keyBytes = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(secretKey, 'Ivan Medvedev', { keySize: 48 / 4, iterations: 1000 });
    console.log(keyBytes.toString());
    var key = new CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.init(keyBytes.words, 32);
    var iv = new CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.init(keyBytes.words.splice(32 / 4), 16);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encryptString, key, { iv: iv, });
    return encrypted;
}

function addExtraByteToChars(str) {
    let strResult = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        strResult += str.charAt(i) + String.fromCharCode(0);
    }
    return strResult;
}
```

**Explanation:**

The C# code in the [Zergatul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53784853/1079901) (Thanks to him/her) was using ASCII to convert the plainText into bytes, while my C# code was using Unicode. Unicode was assigning extra byte to each character in the resultant byte array, which was not affecting the generation of both key and iv bytes, but affecting the result since the length of the encryptedString was dependent on the length of the bytes generated from plainText.
As seen in the following bytes generated for each of them using "Example String" and "Example Key" as the plainText and secretKey respectively -

```
ASCII
clearBytes: [69,120,97,109,112,108,101,32,83,116,114,105,110,103,]
encryptor.Key: [123,213,18,82,141,249,182,218,247,31,246,83,80,77,195,134,230,92,0,125,232,210,135,115,145,193,140,239,228,225,183,13,]
encryptor.IV: [101,74,46,177,46,233,68,252,83,169,211,13,249,61,118,167,]
Result: eQus9GLPKULh9vhRWOJjog==

Unicode:
clearBytes: [69,0,120,0,97,0,109,0,112,0,108,0,101,0,32,0,83,0,116,0,114,0,105,0,110,0,103,0,]
encryptor.Key: [123,213,18,82,141,249,182,218,247,31,246,83,80,77,195,134,230,92,0,125,232,210,135,115,145,193,140,239,228,225,183,13,]
encryptor.IV: [101,74,46,177,46,233,68,252,83,169,211,13,249,61,118,167,]
Result: eAQO+odxOdGlNRB81SHR2XzJhyWtz6XmQDko9HyDe0w=
```

The JS result was similar too, which confirmed that it's using ASCII byte conversion -

```
keyBytes: 7bd512528df9b6daf71ff653504dc386e65c007de8d2877391c18cefe4e1b70d654a2eb12ee944fc53a9d30df93d76a7
key: 7bd512528df9b6daf71ff653504dc386e65c007de8d2877391c18cefe4e1b70d
iv: 654a2eb12ee944fc53a9d30df93d76a7
```

Thus I just need to increase the length of the plainText to make it use Unicode equivalent byte generation (Sorry, not familiar with the term). Since Unicode was assigning 2 space for each character in the byteArray, keeping the second space as 0, I basically created gap in the plainText's characters and filled that gap with character whose ASCII value was 0 using the `addExtraByteToChars()` function. And it made all the difference.

It's a workaround for sure, but started working for my scenario. I suppose this may or may not prove useful to others, thus sharing the findings. If anyone can suggest better implementation of the `addExtraByteToChars()` function (probably some term for this conversion instead of ASCII to Unicode or a better, efficient, and not hacky way to do that), please suggest it.

Comment: You can use `CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE` object instead (equivalent to Unicode encoding in C# code). For example: `CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE.parse('abc').toString()` returns `610062006300`

Comment: It doesn't give the same output. `CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE.parse("Example String").toString();` gives `"4500780061006d0070006c006500200053007400720069006e006700"` while in the case of my hacky method, the string remains the same (just some extra ASCII 0s there)

Comment: I placed `.toString()` only for demonstration purpose. You can pass the result of `parse()` method as first argument for `AES.encrypt`.