# recreating pythons werkzeug.security generate_password_hash in C#

Tags: python, c#, .net, cryptography

Seems simple enough, and there are plenty of examples but I just can't seem to get hashes that verify with werkzeug.security's check_password_hash in python.

```
    private string Generate_Passwd_Hash()
    {
        string _password = "Password";
        string _salt = "cXoZSGKkuGWIbVdr";
        SHA256 MyHash = SHA256.Create();
        byte[] hashable = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_salt + _password);
        byte[] resulthash = MyHash.ComputeHash(hashable);

        return "sha256$" + _salt + "$" + BitConverter.ToString(resulthash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }
```

this should generate;
sha256$cXoZSGKkuGWIbVdr$7f5d63e849f0a2c0c5c2bd6ae4e45ead2ac730c853a1ed3460e227c06c567f49
but doesn't.

EDIT
Reading through the python code for generate_password_hash and it has a default number of iterations of 260000.  Which is probably what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used *werkzeug* but I tried to reproduce your probelem.
I had read the docs of [werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/utils/#werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash) and realized it is used in password validation only, and **not meant to be a universal hashing algorithm**.

The document clearly says

> Hash a password with the given method and salt with a string of the
> given length. The format of the string returned includes the method
> that was used so that check_password_hash() can check the hash.

[hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac) is the hashing algorithm *werkzeug* uses internally(from now on we call it *underlying algorithm*). and you don't need install it because it is in standard library.

The [source code](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/main/src/werkzeug/security.py) of `check_password_hash` shows it generates a random salt before calling underlying algorithm. The salt is to protect from attacks. And it is remembered by the werkzeug framework so that `check_password_hash` can use to validate later.

So to summarize:
`werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash` only guarantee that generated hash can be validated by `check_password_hash`, and no more. You simply cannot(or not supposed to) try to generate same hash by other libraries or languages.

If you really want to compare the hashing algorithm in python and C#, please post another question(or update this question) that compares underlying algorithm(`hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac` which allow specifying `salt` as parameter) with C# version. Note seems in C# there's no built in algorithm for *pbkdf2*, see [Hash Password in C#? Bcrypt/PBKDF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412882/hash-password-in-c-bcrypt-pbkdf2).

Comment: I will have to  call some python from C# to generate the password.  Thanks for your time.