# What size should I use in a CreateSalt class?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hash, asp.net-mvc-4, salt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the optimal length for user password salt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184112/what-is-the-optimal-length-for-user-password-salt)

What size should I use in a CreateSalt class?

```
private static string CreateSalt(int size)
```

Comment: It looks like a method, not a class.

Comment: Possible duplciate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184112/what-is-the-optimal-length-for-user-password-salt

Comment: Stack Overflow [uses a 16 bytes salt](http://code.google.com/p/stackid/source/browse/OpenIdProvider/Current.cs#384)

Comment: Just in case you're encrypting passwords, you might want to consider bcrypt (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873403/net-implementation-of-bcrypt), which generates it's own salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having just done this exact same thing this week, I decided on an byte[8] salt generated by the RNGCryptoServiceProvider class in .Net 4.

Seemed to be a decent size to avoid collisions with other salts.

Si