# bcrypt implementation for windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cryptography, windows-phone, bcrypt

I'm searching for implementation of bcrypt algorithm for Windows Phone. I have already found bcrypt.net library, recommend in [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873403/net-implementation-of-bcrypt). Unfortunately, it seems to be not prepared for windows phone. Downloading source code still wont help - difference between silvelright and .net are to big.

So, did you know any other implementations of bcrypt, which will run on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BCrypt implementation is available in version 10 of our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pki.php) product, which is available for Windows Phone 7 Mango and Windows Phone 8.