# Validating salt in database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I can store the password hashed and with random salt. How can i validate the password?

```vb
    Public Function GetSaltedHash(pw As String, salt As String) As String
    Dim tmp As String = pw & salt


    Using hash As HashAlgorithm = New SHA512Managed()

        Dim saltyPW = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tmp)

        Dim hBytes = hash.ComputeHash(saltyPW)

        Return Convert.ToBase64String(hBytes)
    End Using
End Function

    Public Function CreateNewSalt(size As Integer) As String

    Using rng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider

        Dim data(If(size < 7, 7, size)) As Byte

        rng.GetBytes(data)

        Return Convert.ToBase64String(data)
    End Using
End Function
```

Creating a password with hash and random salt

```vb
Const SaltSize As Integer = 31
Dim pw As String = txt_regpass.Text
Dim dbSalt = CreateNewSalt(SaltSize)

GetSaltedHash(pw, dbSalt))
```

Comment: The answer that code comes from explains how: run the password attempt thru the same hashing mechanism and compare that result to the one stored.  You dont validate the salt but the PW hash - you would need to use the salt originally used to hash the saved PW.

Comment: Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219899/where-do-you-store-your-salt-strings

Comment: This password hashing code is really weak. At the absolute least you should be using [Bcrypt](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com).

Comment: Using the same hashing don't work. I think because of random salt.

Comment: You dont use a new salt when testing an attempt *use the salt originally used to hash the saved PW.*

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: @user6737469 Add another column to your database for the salt. Also, you can store the salt and hash as `BINARY` instead of using Base64 strings` if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you save the salt with the hash value, generally as a prefix—the hash does not need to be secret.

Better: Use [`bcrypt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), it will do it all for you, iterates and is secure.
See the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39602006/451475) by Plutonix.

Simply using `SHA512` or any hash function without iteration is very weak and vulnerable.

Comment: Where can i find the DLL files of bcrypt?
How to import?

Comment: See SO question: [.net implementation of bcrypt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/873403/451475) and/or google. Other options in place of `bcrypt` include `scrypt` and `PBKDF2`. `PBKDF2`  sometimes has a name similar to `RFC2898`.

Comment: @zaph PBKDF2 in the .NET framework is the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Hi! I tried `bcrypt` but i'm having a hard time when verifying the input password and the hashed password from database.

Comment: See the SO answer by [Plutonix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39602006/451475)