# BCrypt Verify stored password hash

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, bcrypt

Storing the hashed password in database is successful. But when verifying if the input password and the hash stored in database, it always returning false.

```
    Dim pw As String = txt_password.Text
    Dim salt As String = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(12)
    Dim hash As String = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(pw, salt)

    With sqlLogin
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", txt_username.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@userpass", hash)
    End With

                Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader = sqlLogin.ExecuteReader()
            If (BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(pw, hash)) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Login Succesful!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                Me.Hide()
                Reader.Close()
            ElseIf Reader.HasRows = False Then
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login Information!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                txt_username.Text = ""
                txt_password.Text = ""
                txt_username.Focus())
            End If
```

Comment: You need to save the salt used to hash the saved PWHash and use that to verify an attempt.  You cant create new salt each time.  Some very good info on the basic concepts here: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: @Plutonix How can i save the salt used to hash the password? Saving into different field of the database? The function `BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify` is used to compare the password and the hash. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Sorry.  Yes, BCrypt saves the salt with the PW hash for you - if you look at the first part of the hashed PW, it is the salt.  You code doesnt seem to be reading the hashed PW from the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especially when it comes to encryption, you ought to have some general idea of the principles and concepts involved. [Salted Password Hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) explains common pitfalls and makes a number of recommendations (one is `BCrypt`, so you may be on the right path).

It looks like you are not reading the stored hash from the DB before you verify.  You don't show how it is saved, but that is important in order for it to verify.

```vb
 ' cuts down on dot operators
 Imports BCryptor = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt
```

#### Create New Logon

```vb
' new user save
Dim sql = "INSERT INTO userlogin (email, username, pwhash) VALUES (@email, @n, @pw)"
' prep:
Dim salt = BCryptor.GenerateSalt(12)    ' == 2^12
Dim hash = BCryptor.HashPassword(tbPass)

' to do: Try/Catch for an email that already exists
Using dbCon As New MySqlConnection(MySQLConnStr),
    cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, dbCon)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = tbEmail
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@n", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = tbUserName
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pw", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = hash
    dbCon.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using
```

#### Verify an Attempt

```vb
Dim bRet As Boolean = False

' login user 
Dim sql = "SELECT pwhash FROM userlogin WHERE email = @email"

Using dbCon As New MySqlConnection(MySQLConnStr),
        cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, dbCon)

    ' data for the where clause
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = tbEmail

    dbCon.Open()
    Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
       ' read from the reader to load data
        If rdr.Read() Then
            ' get the saved hash
            Dim savedHash = rdr.GetString(0)
            bRet = BCryptor.Verify(tbPass, savedHash)
        Else
            bRet = False
        End If
    End Using
    ' return whether the hash verified
    Return ret
End Using
```

**Notes**

- `DbConnection`, `DbCommand` and `DbDataReader` all implement `Dispose` which means they may very well allocate resources which need to be released.  The code uses each of them in a `Using` block.  This creates them at the start and disposes of them at the end of the Block.
- This uses an email for the unique identifier because there are a lot of Steves out there.  This means the SQL will return one record at most.
- After loading the hashed pw from the DB, use ***it*** to verify the password attempt entered.  Your code seems to be creating a new hash (and doesnt actually load anything from the DB).

---

The random salt originally generated when the account was created becomes part of the hash (as well as the work factor you used) as shown here:

```vb
Dim pw = "My!Weak#Pa$$word"
Dim salt = BCryptor.GenerateSalt(12)
Dim hash = BCryptor.HashPassword(pw, salt)

Console.WriteLine(salt)
Console.WriteLine(hash)
```

Output:

> $2a$12$XPC20niJIhZPxaKvJkSUfO
>   $2a$12$XPC20niJIhZPxaKvJkSUfO/rwIetoScCze.tOcVS/aJzowvjpCPlq

The `12` after `"$2a$"` is the work factor.