# username and password not detected when they are in the database

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

Trying to do a Log In system in VB using mysql as a database but its coming up as username and password not detected when they are in the database

I am trying to do a LogIn system in `VB` using `mysql` as a database but it's coming up as username and password not detected when they are in the database.

My second example of code: my register account code in which I am able to add to my database just not reading from it and log in.
(Register code and log in code are in different forms)

Log in code which doesn't work:

```
 Private Sub Button_login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_login.Click
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=librarydatabase"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        conn.Open()
        query = "select * from librarydatabase.users where Users= ' " & TextBox_Username.Text & " ' and Passwordhash=' " & TextBox_Password.Text & " ' "

        command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader
        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0
        While reader.Read
            count = count + 1

        End While

        If count = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You are logged in")

        ElseIf count > 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Username or password already exist")

        Else MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password")

        End If

        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()

    End Try
End Sub
```

My Register code which works fine and adds records to my database:

```
Private Sub Button_Register2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Register2.Click
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=librarydatabase"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        conn.Open()
        query = "insert into librarydatabase.users (Users,Passwordhash) values ('" & TextBox_Username.Text & "','" & TextBox_Password.Text & "')"

        command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader

        MessageBox.Show("you are registered")
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: How would a user ever be able to type a password hash into a textbox?

Comment: I was planning to implement one later, Ive only just started coding and didnt know when to do a hash so i named it that just to be safe.

Comment: @ShayaanKiani You might as well get off to a good start for storing password data: have a read of [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Comment: ...and/or answer lovingly handcrafted just yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39602006/1070452