# How safely can I assume unicity of a part of SHA1 hash?

Tags: security, sha1

I'm currently using a SHA1 to somewhat shorten an url:

```
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("salt-" + url)
```

How safe is it to use only the first 8 characters of the SHA1 as a unique identifier, like GitHub does for commits apparently?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060259/do-cryptographic-hashes-provide-really-unique-results can help here.

Answer (score 11):

To calculate the probability of a collision with a given length and the number of hashes that you have, see the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). I don't know the number of hashes that you are going to have, but here are some examples. 8 hexadecimal characters is 32 bits, so for about 100 hashes the probability of a collision is about 1/1,000,000, for 10,000 hashes it's about 1/100, for 100,000 it's 3/4 etc.

See the table in the [Birthday attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack#The_mathematics) article on Wikipedia to find a good hash length that would satisfy your needs. For example if you want the collision to be less likely than 1/1,000,000,000 for a set of more than 100,000 hashes then use 64 bits, or 16 hexadecimal digits.

It all depends on how many hashes are you going to have and what probability of a collision are you willing to accept (because there is always some probability, even if insanely small).

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about a SHA-1 in hexadecimal, then you're only getting 4 bits per character, for a total of 32 bits. The chances of a collision are inversely proportional to the square root of that maximum value, so about 1/65536. If your URL shortener gets used much, it probably won't take terribly long before you start to see collisions.

As for alternatives, the most obvious is probably to just maintain a counter. Since you need to store a table of URLs to translate your shortened URL back to the original, you basically just store each new URL in your table. If it was already present, you give its existing number. Otherwise, you insert it and give it a new number. Either way, you give that number to the user.

Comment: The shortener won't be used at a large scale first - we plan to use it for tracking purposes; the end-user won't have to copy/paster it. We'd love to get rather short urls instead of a long SHA1 though; would you have an alternate algorithm to suggest maybe?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. The output of SHA1 is effectively random with regards to the input (the output of a good hash function changes in half of its bits based on a one-bit change in the input, and SHA1, while not perfect, is pretty good), and by taking a 32-bit (assuming 8 hex digits) subset of the 160-bit output, you reduce the output space from 2^160 to 2^32 values. All things being equal, which they never are, this would significantly reduce the difficulty of finding a collision.

However, if the hash function's input must be a valid URL, that significantly reduces the number of possible inputs. @rsp points out the birthday problem, but given this, I'm not sure exactly how applicable it is at least in its simple form. Also, it largely assumes that there are no other precautions in place.

I would be more interested in why you are doing this. Is this about URLs that the user will need to remember and type? If so, tacking on a bunch of random hexadecimal digits is probably a bad idea. Is it a URL or URL parameter that will just be passed around programmatically? Then, I wouldn't care much about length. Either way, there are probably better ways to do what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a *binary* output for SHA1 and [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encode the result, you will get much higher information density per character; you can have the same 8-character names, but rather than only `16^8` (`2^32`) possibilities, you'll have `64^8` (`2^48`) possibilities.

Using the assumption that the 50% probability-of-collision scales with [1.177*sqrt(N)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Reverse_problem), using a Base64-style encoding will require 256 times more inputs than the hex-output before reaching the 50% chance of collision probability.