# C# Adding more hashing algorithms to use

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, hash

I am working on a program that allows users to hash words, I know it's basic I am still learning :). But, I have found that there are only 6 main hashing algorithms included in the .NET framework I have. Is there a way to add more as this would be a key feature in my program? Any help or ideas thanked

**EDIT**

A way I am think of is having a file that contains the algorithm or something similar that allows me to call it with a string and then return the hash.

By add more I mean being able to call it within a function or call a file with parameters then having it return the hash

Comment: This [Which cryptographic hash function should I choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800685/which-cryptographic-hash-function-should-i-choose) can be helpful for you.

Comment: That's the one I saw first, it says that they're then only ones supported. I am just wondering how I can implement more; e.g having other files that contain the algorithm then calling that file. Thank you anyway, it was a good pointer :)

Comment: What do you mean "add more"? So that you can call it through `HashAlgorithm.Create("")`?

Comment: Check edit, I have stated two ways I would like it

Comment: You can add it by writing the code implementing any hashing algorithm you want. I'm a bit puzzled about how many of those you think you might need, and why.

Comment: I want a lot as it will allow users to specifically chose the one they want out of many. What do you mean by "writing the code" that doesn't tell me much, also I don't see how you would need to understand why I am wanting a lot of hash function in my code... I am new with c# so you will need to explain

Comment: Reading the question after edit: I get the impression, you want something like a [Plugin-System](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b6174b62). Where you can just put a dll in the Program Folder and the Algos implemented in that dll will pop up as selectable items in the program, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's the basic fundamental that I want. Just to call a file and then generate the hash or something. However, it would be better if it could be done within the program so it may be quicker