# MD5 and SHA512 sizes and security

Tags: php, security, encryption, hash, cryptography

To my knowledge if you talk about `md5` it can store up to `32 characters`. I'm aware that if you exceed the `32 characters` it will still hash it perfectly fine but it might actually be the same `hash` as `md5( 'a' )` though, unlikely.

Isn't it potentially very dangerous and insecure then to use a (md5) `salt` in `md5` or even not checking for the `input` length of the `password` + `salt`?

*Example 1:*

```
$pass = md5( 'this is a password' );
$salt = md5( 'this is a salt' );

// Will exceed 32 range and might therefore equal md5( 'a' ) -
// if so this will pass an authorization such as login
md5( $pass . $salt );
```

*Example 2:*

```
// 32 character password
$pass = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
$salt = 'salt';

// Will also exceed 32 range due to no length check and might equal md5( 'a' )
md5( $pass . $salt );
```

Should you not do:

```
$pass = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
$salt = 'salt';

if ( strlen( $pass ) + strlen( $salt ) > 32 ) 
  exit;

else
  md5( $pass . $salt );
```

Also, where is the limit for `sha512`? `512 characters`?

Comment: your underlying assumption is simply wrong. it produces a "32-character hexadecimal number." that has nothing to do with the length of the input. its often used to produce a hash of a file that could be ANY length

Comment: @Dagon Care to explain? `A-F` and `0-9` can only generate enough `hashes` for `32 characters`. So, if you exceed `32 characters` won't it use a hash that will match something within the `32 characters`?

Comment: @user2864740 Let me rephrase the question:  How long can the input be before it will start using identical hashes within that range?

Comment: @user286470 Hm. I see. So, there is always possibilities on duplicates because 32 ^ 255 is of course much larger than 32 ^ 16. But it is however true that if you generate 32 ^ 16.x MD5 hashes that you have a 100% chance of a duplicate, Correct?

Comment: @user2864740 I would obviously accept as answer but you commented =(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Preface:**

*Neither* MD5 nor SHA-x are suitable for password hashes; ignoring the fact MD5 is cryptographically broken and should be phased out in general, both hash families are *too fast* and are not suited for this problem - This is because the hashes are too fast, and humans often choose weak/poor password which severely compromises the domain, which makes brute-forcing MD5/SHA-x passwords practical.

For password hashing, use [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) instead (via [`crypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)), which is standard in any self-respecting PHP build. Other options, not supplied standard in PHP, are scrypt and even the more vulnerable PBKDF2.

The *best* thing to do is not re-invent the wheel but to use an existing/tested library which will use a valid hash algorithm (ie. bcrypt), and mitigate issues with incorrect database access, authentication testing, salt generation, etc. As of PHP 5.5+ the [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) functions can be used, although it is still only part of the system.

---

**Response**:

The *output* (range) of MD5 is 32 hex characters representing 128 bits; the *input* (domain) is effectively unbounded. For SHA-512 the values are 128 characters / 512 bits, respectively. (Note the number of bits of effective security considered is *less* than the actual number of bits in the range.)

Since *neither* MD5 nor SHA-x are perfect hash functions then there *will* be collisions over the domain even when it is less than the range - *but the range is so huge (and a valid cryto-hash has certain properties) that it just doesn't matter.*

That is, the resulting hashes are not guaranteed unique, but rather (and especially with more bits) it is [***extremely improbable** that a duplicate will be accidentally (or even purposefully) found*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014090/is-it-safe-to-ignore-the-possibility-of-sha-collisions-in-practice). The expected collision rate can be estimated by the [Birthday Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem); the Pigeon Hole principle also applies, but the chance of *a* duplicate is so infinitesimally close to 100% before this, such isn't very applicable.

However, this is *not a problem* in a proper design. This is because [cryptographic hash functions are designed with certain properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) (which also explains why MD5 is *not suitable* in such a role):

> The ideal cryptographic hash function has four main properties:
>
> - it is easy to compute the hash value for any given message
> - *it is infeasible to generate a message that has a given hash*
> - it is infeasible to modify a message without changing the hash
> - *it is infeasible to find two different messages with the same hash*

Do keep in mind that as of yet there have been [no [reported] found collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Comparison_of_SHA_functions) on SHA-1/2/3. This is because they are still suitable cryptographic hash functions. (See duskwoof's comment about SHA-1.)

Also, consider that there are [*less atoms in the observable universe*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Matter_content_.E2.80.94_number_of_atoms) (10^80 or ~2^280) than the range of a SHA-512 hash! This is part of the reason why/how cryptographic hash functions are considered secure.

Comment: SHA-1 has been considered weak since 2005. No collisions are currently known, but [theoretical attacks have been discovered](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html) that significantly reduce its collision resistance (from 2^80 to 2^69 operations).

Comment: @duskwuff That is a good point. I've left it still categorized as "good" but added a note about referring to your comment. Feel free to edit the post (or demand I make more changes) as warranted.

Comment: However, as for password hashing, you would rather look for a pre-image attack.

Comment: Item 4 resembles to 'find m1!=m2 such that H(m1)=H(m2)'. This is not what you’re looking for when you’re looking for a password that results in a given hash. Instead you are looking for 'find m2 such that H(m1)=H(m2) for a given H(m1)', which would be item 2.

Comment: @Gumbo Ah, yes. I indeed focused that on two arbitrarily chosen values to match the above. I've spread the focus now.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not dangerous/insecure.   There's no real security requirement that two different passwords won't authenticate the same credential!   In fact, you may be under the impression that MD5 will hash all of the first 2^32-1 values uniquely - in fact that is not the case.

In fact, MD5 does not "store" a unique value of any kind.  There are many values that will hash to any given MD5 output.

sha2/512 has, as the name implies, 512 bits in the hash - double the length.

Comment: Which two values of the first 2^32 - 1 does MD5 hash to the same value?

Comment: Ha ha ha, @GregS.   You're with the NSA, aren't you. :p

(if you're not actually joking, the answer is: we don't know (probably.  those of us who don't wear shiny suits and work someplace in Maryland, anyway))

Comment: (I think the current shortest known collision is 128 bytes)