# Unique VARCHAR(65535) field per <ID> in MySQL

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique, varchar

Are there solutions to maintain a `VARCHAR(65535)` field unique per `ID` in MySQL?

Comment: *unique per ID* -  what does that mean?

Comment: ID is the primary key entity.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a hashing function on field's value and store it in a separate unique field on the same table.

So your table would be something like this:

```
create table my_table (
   id integer not null primary key,
   text_content varchar(65535) not null,
   text_hash varchar(128) not null unique
);
```

When inserting on that table, you will compute **sha256** hash for `text_content` field and store it in `text_hash` field. That way you can be pretty sure `text_content` values are unique on your table.

If you like DB SIDE programming, you can put this logic on a trigger provided **MySQL** supports them.

Comment: how do I deal with collisions?

Comment: Collisions would be **extremely** rare. Don't think you will find them. That's what those kind of algorithms were designed for. Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014090/is-it-safe-to-ignore-the-possibility-of-sha-collisions-in-practice

Comment: This could have been solved 100% bulletproof with a binary comparison in case of a hash collision + an autoincremented secondary field for key uniqueness in case of collisions. Isn't there any database solution that would perform such a task?

Comment: That could also be a generated column using the sha2() function.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, what do you mean? 2 hash columns with different algorithms? from what I see, `sha256` belongs to `sha2` family. What would be a secondary choice to mate with `sha256`?

Comment: @Nick - my comment didn't address your collision problem. I'm just suggesting an improvement to the answer, using [MySQL 5.7 generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html). Something like: `text_hash varchar(128) as sha2(text_content, 256)  unique`. This way you keep everything within the table definition. No triggers or additional code in your application required.