# Primary key cannot hold more than 767 or 1000 character as primary key

Tags: mysql, indexing, duplicates, unique-constraint

I'm trying to create a table which one of their columns will hold characters more than 5000 characters and I don't want any row for this column to be repeated so I used a primary key to make every row in this column not save again when it's already exist

But the problem is when I'm trying to create this column with `column_name VARCHAR(5500) Primary key` it's giving me this error
`Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes`

I searched a lot and found that `InnoDB` engine accepts only 767 characters as max length and in `MYISAM` engine accepts 1000 character but this doesn't help me because this column maybe hold more than 5000 character

What I'm looking for is a way to create a column which no one of its rows can be repeated and accepts many characters

```
CREATE TABLE data_table (
    date_time VARCHAR(100),
    message VARCHAR(5500) PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET latin1
```

Comment: Seems pointless you would just have to change 1 character for it not to be seen as a duplicate.

Comment: can you give me any suggestion for more effective solution ?

Comment: Run a `select` first? You can't index 5000 chars.

Comment: I found that `Memory` Engine can hold 3072  character as max length maybe it's can work although that i was hope to found engine who can hold more that this or if there's no limitations 

Comment: Another thread suggested storing a hash. You'd just need to worry about hash collision in that scenario. If the odds of that are acceptable for your app could do that.

Comment: Change latin1 to utf8mb4

Comment: Please share more details. Why do you need to use a primary key on a message?

Comment: @Dharman changing to utf8mb4 cuts the limit to 767/4 or 1000/4 _characters_.  The index limit is "bytes"; the number in VARCHAR is "characters".

Answer (score 1):

You have hit a fundamental limitation. Sadly, no amount of negotiation or hacking will find you a way to make an index as long as you need. Therefore, a unique index is not a solution to your problem of preventing duplicate text strings.

Many people store a [hash of long text fields](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html) along with the text.

[SHA-256 is a decent choice for a hash](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2). The issue with hashes is the chance of a hash collision. That is, it is possible that two different text strings will generate the exact same hash. With SHA-256 or larger hashes, [that chance is very low indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014090/is-it-safe-to-ignore-the-possibility-of-sha-collisions-in-practice).

If you work with SHA-256, you need a column defined like this. (32 bytes is the same as 256 bits, of course.)

```
text_hash BINARY(32)
```

Then when you go to insert text you can do this.

```
INSERT INTO tbl (text, text_hash) VALUES(?, UNHEX(SHA2(?, 256));
```

If you make your `text_hash` into a unique index you'll have a way of preventing duplicates by throwing an error when trying.  Something like this.

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX no_text_dups_please ON tbl(text_hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

Needs : "[one] column will hold characters (more than 5000 characters) and I don't want any row for this column to be repeated"

PRIMARY KEY add a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on the field(s) specified, but if you don't need to use it as PRIMARY KEY use only UNIQUE. In addition, I would **not** recommend UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on large text column.

I would recommend you to check the unicity of your data by making and storing hashs of your texts.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the Hash is one way.  (I think the latest MariaDB has a technique for doing that by magic!)  Here's another approach:

For many reasons, you should switch from MyISAM to InnoDB, but I will ignore that for this Q&A.

```
CREATE TABLE data_table (
    date_time VARCHAR(100),
    message VARCHAR(5500) PRIMARY KEY
    INDEX(message(100))
) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4   -- since you might get non-English test, including Emoji.
```

(The "100" is a tradeoff between speed and space.)

But you will have to do an extra test:

```
SELECT 1 FROM data_table WHERE message = ?
```

If you get something back, you have a dup -- take action.  Else do an INSERT.

Oops, I do need to insist on InnoDB -- at least if you could have conflicting connections inserting the same message:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT 1 FROM data_table WHERE message = ? FOR UPDATE;
if ... then handle dup and don't COMMIT
INSERT INT data_table (date_time, message) VALUES (?, ?);
COMMIT;
```

You might want to hide all that inside a Stored Procedure.