# Cipher algorithm without initialization vector

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I'm looking for a cipher algorithm which doesn't require an initialization vector. I use the NodeJS function [`crypto.createCipheriv`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatecipherivalgorithm-key-iv-options) which documents at least the option to pass no initialization vector.

> If the cipher does not need an initialization vector, iv may be null.

```
const encryptionAlgoritm = 'aes-192-cbc';
const encryptionKey = '...';
const cipher = createCipheriv(encryptionAlgoritm, encryptionKey, null);
// Error: Missing IV for cipher aes-192-cbc
```

Which OpenSSL algorithm can be used without the `iv` parameter?

Background: I don't need to decrypt the encrypted value. I want to pass the encrypted value to the database and also query the database with the encrypted value. Therefore the encryption algorithm needs to be bijective.

Comment: You could use the ECB algorithm. However, it is not secure (neither is CBC).

Comment: Why then use encryption in the first place? Why not work with checksums? I see no benefit here using encryption. For a one way thing, checksums should work fine.

Comment: @Marc, the transformation needs to be bijective to support the database query use case. Since I assume, that checksum algorithms may return the same hash for different values, I'm looking for a bijective encryption algorithm. I don't want to store the clear values in the database. Reasonable?

Comment: Since you don't need decryption, a *cryptographic* hash function like SHA256 with its low [collision probabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4014407/9014097) could possibly be sufficient with regard to bijectivity.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should be using a cryptographic hash function instead. If you're processing a million inputs a second with a 192-bit cryptographic hash function, your chance of finding a collision before the sun turns into a red giant and swallows the earth would be vanishingly small. (It would take about 350 trillion years to have a 1% chance of a collision.)