# What is the probability of md5 collision if I pass in 2^32 sets of string?

Tags: md5

What is the probability of md5 collision if I pass in 2^32 sets of string?

Can I say the answer is just 2^32/2^128 = 1/1.2621774e-29 as the length of bit of md5 hash is 128?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This question is similar to the so-called ["birthday paradox"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

> In probability theory, the **birthday problem** or **birthday paradox** concerns the probability that, in a set of *n* randomly chosen people, some pair of them will have the same birthday. By the pigeonhole principle, the probability reaches 100% when the number of people reaches 367 (since there are 366 possible birthdays, including February 29). However, 99% probability is reached with just 57 people, and 50% probability with 23 people. These conclusions are based on the assumption that each day of the year (except February 29) is equally probable for a birthday.
>
> The mathematics behind this problem led to a well-known cryptographic attack called the [birthday attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack), which uses this probabilistic model to reduce the complexity of cracking a hash function.

According to the Wikipedia article, the chance of a collision when choosing *n* = 2<sup>32</sup> random numbers from a space with *d* = 2<sup>128</sup> numbers is approximately:

[image: Generalized birthday problem math]

If you [work this calculation out](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n+%3D+2%5E32%2C+d+%3D+2%5E128%2C+1+-+%28%28d-1%29%2Fd%29+%5E+%28n%28n-1%29%2F2%29) the chance is about 2.7×10<sup>-20</sup>. This is a very small probability, but notice that it is 9 orders of magnitude higher than your proposed calculation.

Comment: And that is assuming that the md5 algrorithm has a perfectly even spread of hashes. Since it does not, your chances of collision are even greater.