# Unique file name based on SRC attibute

Tags: php, md5, unique

On my project I have image linked from other domain

```
<img src="http://www.somewhere.com/images/whatever-image.jpg">
```

I would like to resave it locally with some name **based on its original src-attribute** the way I can check later if I have already saved this image locally or not. My question is, when I use *md5()* on *src*-attribute is it then unique? Example:

```
$src = "http://www.somewhere.com/images/whatever-image.jpg"
if (file_exists('local_path'.md5($src)) {
...
}
```

Can I rely on *md5()* in this case? If not, how this can be done properly?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032209/is-md5-still-good-enough-to-uniquely-identify-files

Comment: Rob, yes, I knew about issues with md5(). Still looking for possibility to make it for my case really unique.

Comment: ok - try http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: If I go with timestamp I cannot recheck it later based on the src-attribute, right?

Comment: Reading your other comments - you want to accept a url string create a unique id from that string and then beable to decypher later? - what happens if you get the same string again?

Comment: If there is collision the file will be just replaced. If the possibility of the collision is tiny, it is no problem for me. Saying, one to 1 000 000 ;) But I do not know how tiny the possibility is.

Comment: I think you will be ok - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201705/how-many-random-elements-before-md5-produces-collisions

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you! I wonder why I have not found the question while searching.

Answer (score 2):

MD5 is quite safe to use in this case. The fast hashing time, which makes it unsafe for cryptographic purposes, is actually a bonus here.

for the probability of collisions read for example this: [How many random elements before MD5 produces collisions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201705/how-many-random-elements-before-md5-produces-collisions)

on the other hand, for your purpose it would be enough to simply strip those characters from the source attribute value that are not allowed in a file path, i. e.

`$localFileName = str_replace(array('/', ':'), '', $src); //may need to strip '&', too..`

this way the filenames are more human readable and easier to process further if the need arises

Answer (score 0):

I think you can. Collision still may happen but it is very rare possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try `SHA1()`, it will collide less than `MD5()`.  However, unless you need to obfuscate the URL, you don't need to use these hashes at all.  Simply save the string into a text field in your database, maybe running `url_encode()` if needed.  This way you can scale indefinitely without worrying about a collision.

Comment: Those would be some pritty untidy filenames

Comment: I cannot use database. It is a kind of on-fly check if the file already exists or not. I will look for sha1().

Answer (score 0):

Add current timestamp to the path. This will make sure that the path is unique.

Comment: And how can I check if the file exists later if I am not aware of the timestamp it has been saved?