# Calculate MD5 and SHA1 simultaneously on large file

Tags: python, hash, md5, sha1, crc32

I'm writing a Python program to find duplicate files. Calculating MD5 and comparing file-size is not 100% fool-proof since it is possible for two different files to have the same file-size and MD5 (collision probability 2^128).

I was wondering then, perhaps if I add another hash such as SHA1 (2^160) or CRC32 (2^32) to the mix, would that greatly increase the ability to identify unique files, i.e. compare both MD5 and SHA1 of a file for uniqueness? Is SHA1 or CRC32 preferable for this secondary check?

If so, how do I calculate both MD5 and SHA1/CRC32 simultaneously while iterating thru 1MB blocks of a very large file to avoid reading the large file twice? This is what I have for MD5:

```
def md5(fname):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(2 ** 20), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()
```

Currently my code, after checking for identical MD5's, would run *filecmp.cmp* on both files as the final check. This is obviously resource intensive and not efficient.

I'm using SQLite to store these hashes. I assume it is slower than Python Lists but doesn't suffer from insufficient memory when processing billions of files.

Comment: 2^128 is misleading but the actual probability of a collision is small enough that you don't need to worry, MD5 is fine (for non-sensitive applications) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032209/is-md5-still-good-enough-to-uniquely-identify-files / https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12677/strength-of-md5-in-finding-duplicate-files/12679

Comment: Thanks for the comment. "Small enough" probability won't be enough for someone with 500+GB of photo images to sort thru and eliminate duplicates. Wondering if SHA1/CRC32 is enough to "guarantee"  that. Perhaps filecmp.cmp is the only fool-proof way...

Comment: Using two hash functions should give you enough certainty to sleep peacefully ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have the hardest part done. You just have to feed the chunks you read to another hasher:

```
def calculate_hashes(fname):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    hash_sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(2 ** 20), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
            hash_sha1.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest(), hash_sha1.hexdigest()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet! Will implement it and time the results to see how it compares with using filecmp.cmp. Should be much faster...