# Best way of comparing two files in python and why?

Tags: python, hashlib

I have two files a.txt and b.txt, So i am trying to compare using hash like below.

```
#getting hash of files and comparing
file1 = hashlib.md5(open('a.txt', 'rb').read()).hexdigest()
file2 = hashlib.md5(open('b.txt', 'rb').read()).hexdigest() 
file1==file2--> returns True or False
```

this is one way and also we can do using filecmp as below

```
filecmp.cmp('a.txt','b.txt')--> returns True or False
```

In both of these ways which is better and why?

Comment: what do u need compare? line by line, or each line in all the document? could you please give us some example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is MD5 still good enough to uniquely identify files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032209/is-md5-still-good-enough-to-uniquely-identify-files)

Comment: I'd encourage you to compare it yourself by timing it (with different file sizes).

Comment: Note that by default (with `shallow=True`) `cmp` will compare files by `os.stat`. With `shallow=False` it will compare the files content

Comment: @soon how that que will be duplicate, my question was about comparision between these two

Comment: I think no one understood question, except @user803422. tq man..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filecmp.cmp('a.txt','b.txt', shallow=False)` is just what you need for comparing 2 files.

`hashlib.md5()` will add complexity, be more CPU intensive, take longer, and most importantly it will give a wrong result when 2 different files have the same md5 hash.